# How to activate the child theme in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I create a new style.css and use it in child theme. And I create a new folder in wp-content and name it as themename-child and upload the style.css that I created. Now, I go to wp dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes and I look the child theme that I create. And I found this error:

```
Broken Themes

The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a stylesheet and a template.

Name    Description
Accesspress Lite    The parent theme is missing. Please install the "AccesspressLite" parent theme.
```

Is there anything that I need to upload? Please help me. I'm new in WordPress. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem here is that you must specify the parent template in commented area of your child style.css

Example from Wordpress Codex

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fourteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fourteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fourteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfourteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fourteen-child
*/

@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css");
```

Line with

```
Template:     twentyfourteen
```

is what your need. Your parent theme must be in corresponding folder, in this example, themes/twentyfourteen.

Also, in your parent template you must load style.css via get_stylesheet_uri() for child theme to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems clear to me that you need to install the Parent Theme, which is required for child theme installation...

`The parent theme is missing. Please install the "AccesspressLite" parent theme.`

The whole purpose of the child theme is that it feeds it's adjustments into the parent theme, so you don't have to adjust parent theme settings.